# Drawing decorated line in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm looking for a way to draw a decorated line in the map, specifically a line with squares or triangles along it, with the shapes being equally spaced along the line and drawn perpendicular to it. Here's an examples of the result I need:

[image: line decorated with triangles]

I've tried using a `CompositeSymbol`, consisting of a `SimpleLineSymbol` and a `SimpleMarkerSymbol`, but the markers show on every vertex of the line, instead of equally spaced along it, and always with the same orientation.

[image: not equally spaced triangles]

Is there a way to create a line symbol that achieves the effect I'm looking for?